# how to create custom STS in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4. I want to implement Secure token service using WIF.
 I have installed identity and access tool in VS 2012.

What is the proper way to use STS in MVC4 - whether to use third party or to develop own custom STS?

Also is it good to use the identiy & access provided by microsoft? or should we develop own STS?

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own STS is a complicated thing to do. You may wish to consider using something already written instead like Thinktecture's IdentityServer

http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/

It comes with both a pre-written MVC4 website you can use, and examples on how to re-host the libraries in your own site if required.

Identity and Access is used to easily configure your app to use an existing STS. It's not relevant to developing one. Although for the record, yes; use it.

Comment: How can I use this existing STS? is it safe to use existing STS instead of custom STS?

Comment: How can I use this existing STS? is it safe to use existing STS instead of custom STS?